# Mongodb: update many array elements by index with different data

Tags: arrays, mongodb, go

I get a mongo document like below

```
// document example
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("62c447e3cf7aee7b78d39908"), 
"gid" : "1234", 
"branch_trans" : [ 
  { "branch_id" : "branchId123", "op" : "test_op" },
  { "branch_id" : "branchId456", "op" : "test_op" },
  { "branch_id" : "branchId789", "op" : "test_op"}] 
}
```

Golang struct:

```golang
type GlobalTrans struct {
    ID         primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
    Gid        string             `bson:"gid,omitempty"`
    BranchTrans []BranchTrans `bson:"brach_trans,omitempty"`
}

type BranchTrans struct {
    BranchID     string     `bson:"branch_id,omitempty"`
    Op           string     `bson:"op,omitempty"`
}
```

I have a `startPositon` variable, and an array variable `[]branches`, now I want to update `branch_trans` from the index `startPositon`  using `[]branches`.
For example, if `startPositon = 1` and `[]branches` is

```
[
  { "branch_id" : "branchId456", "op" : "op1" },
  { "branch_id" : "branchId789", "op" : "op2"}
]
```

After updating, the document will look like:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("62c447e3cf7aee7b78d39908"), 
"gid" : "1234", 
"branch_trans" : [ 
  { "branch_id" : "branchId123", "op" : "test_op" },
  { "branch_id" : "branchId456", "op" : "op1" },
  { "branch_id" : "branchId789", "op" : "op2"}] 
}
```

I don't know how to do that, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can [`$slice`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) the not changed array and concat with the [`$concatArray`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) to get the expected `branch_trans`. Then can you update the existing `branch_trans` key inside document using [`$replaceWith`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceWith/) and [`$setField`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setField/) with aggregate pipeline.

```js
db.branch.aggregate([
  {
    "$replaceWith": {
      "$setField": {
        input: "$$ROOT",
        "field": "branch_trans",
        "value": {
          "$concatArrays": [
            {
              $slice: [
                "$branch_trans",
                0,
                1
              ]
            },
            [
              {
                "branch_id": "branchId456",
                "op": "op1"
              },
              {
                "branch_id": "branchId789",
                "op": "op2"
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/E-GUWwNG-1X)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is aggregate operation atomic? Does it need to begin a transaction ? And what should I do if I just want to add some new branches array?